# Centering a form with CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, center

I have written a form in html/css using the following code:

```
.login_form_wrapper{
float:left;
padding:60px;
width:55%;
padding:80px 100px 78px 100px;
text-align:center;
}
```

How do I center the  so that it neatly fits inside the center of the users screen?

I have tried to edit the CSS for the past several hours with no joy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that the CSS classes you are using are used in more than one place. What is causing your issue is that on this wrapper DIV:

`<div class="login_form_wrapper register_wrapper">`

you have classes applying `float: left;` this needs to be removed and add `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. This is also a good solution. I noticed that this makes it fully responsive on mobile devices. Thanks... saved me a lot of time.

Comment: user3931836 Yes I always test for responsive design. Glad this could be of help.

Comment: Kyle any idea how to center the "Gold Plan" white box on the home page?

Comment: user3931836 what is the URL so I can see it again? That was removed from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the style class

```
.login_form_wrapper{

    position: sticky;
    left: 25%;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Comment: Jose!! Thank you so much! I have no idea how you worked it out so quickly. I've been messing about for hours!! You are a genius!! Any tips on how I can learn and understand CSS? I have no idea why it works but it does....

Comment: Change to position: sticky, so that it is fully responsive, I already updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I played around in the inspector for a few minutes and found that this css looked nice.

```
.login_form_wrapper {
    margin : 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```